# veth down after reboot on bionic beaver (netplan) systemd

Tags: server, 18.04, systemd, netplan

First, please forgive my lame markdown skills.

Running Bionic Beaver:
`host:~# lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic`
Can't seem to figure out the best way to make sure my veth devices automatically "link up" after reboot.

My use case for the veth:
I use them for attaching local network bridges to containers.  I do this because attaching docker macvlan directly to the bridge inhibits communication between the containers and their host.

Now that that is out of the way:
I've tried putting: 
`ip link set veth1a up
ip link set veth5a up`
 in /etc/rc.local *I had to create new and add execute permissions*, but did nothing upon reboot.

I have the interfaces listed in netplan, but this only successfully brings up the bridge side of the veth e.g veth1b:

`network:
    ethernets:
        enp131s0f0:
            dhcp4: false
        enp131s0f1:
            dhcp4: false
        enp6s0:
            dhcp4: false
        enp7s0:
            dhcp4: false
        veth1a:
            dhcp4: false
        veth1b:
            dhcp4: false
        veth5a:
            dhcp4: false
        veth5b:
            dhcp4: false
    bridges:
        br0:
            dhcp4: true
            interfaces:
              - enp6s0
              - enp7s0
              - veth1b
        br5:
            dhcp4: false
            interfaces:
              - vlan5
              - veth5b
    vlans:
        vlan5:
          id: 5
          link: br0
          dhcp4: false 
version: 2`

I also have some systemd configs to create the veths in the first place, but I don't know how to tell systemd to "admin up" the veth1a and veth5a.  This is what I need help with.
`host:~# cat /etc/systemd/network/25-veth-*
[NetDev]
Name=veth1a
Kind=veth
[Peer]
Name=veth1b
[NetDev]
Name=veth5a
Kind=veth
[Peer]
Name=veth5b`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not working with `/etc/rc.local`, I would have thought this would run late enough to work; but I think you're quite close with the `systemd` config already.

Add:

`[Network]
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=true`

for each of the veth interfaces. By default systemd-networkd will not bring up interfaces if they have no IP addresses directly attached to them.

Veths are not currently directly supported in netplan, but they may be added in the future to make setting this up simpler.